# Circular point scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, svg

I'm aware of the external d3-scale-radial.js library, but I'm only going for a one dimensional circular scale (not 2 dimensional like radial bar charts or line charts). So I'm hoping I don't need to include a whole additional library for what seems to be a fairly simple task. Here is a image version I drafted using illustrator:

[image]

You'll note that there is no "y" axis here. It's basically a point scale, but rendered as a circle. While this is simpler than multi-dimensional radial charts, precision and scalability are important to me, so I'm reluctant to brute force it by appending `line`s as tick marks then conjuring up some trigonometric voodoo to position the circles at the exact decimal values along the circumference of the circle -- which seems to be the only native d3 solution.

### Question

Is there anything that native d3 can offer to simplify a simple radial point chart? Or should I throw in the towel and embrace the radial.js library for the time being?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no native D3 scale for this, but you don't need any scale: a simple trigonometric math will do.

For the x position multiply the radius for the cosine of your value, while for the y position you multiply the radius for the sine of your value. Since your values go from `0` to `1`, you position your circles with just this (where `r` is the radius):

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return r * Math.cos(d * Math.PI * 2)
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
    return r * Math.sin(d * Math.PI * 2)
})
```

However, since your axis starts at the top (that is, *12 o'clock*), subtract it by `Math.PI / 2`:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return r * Math.cos(d * Math.PI * 2 - Math.PI / 2)
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
    return r * Math.sin(d * Math.PI * 2 - Math.PI / 2)
})
```

Also, if your values don't go from `0` to `1` anymore use a basic linear scale for mapping them.

The most complicated thing is drawing the axis, but it's not that complicated.

Here is a demo using `[0.1, 0.25, 0.7]` as data:

```js
const w = 300,
  h = 300,
  r = 100;

const data = [0.1, 0.25, 0.7];

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + [w / 2, h / 2] + ")");

const axisLine = g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", r)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "black");

const axisGroup = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(0, 1.05, 0.05))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (-90 + (d * 360)) + ")";
  });

axisGroup.append("line")
  .attr("x1", r - 4)
  .attr("x2", r + 4)
  .style("stroke", "black");

const points = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .style("fill", "dodgerblue")
  .attr("r", 8)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return r * Math.cos(d * Math.PI * 2 - Math.PI / 2)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return r * Math.sin(d * Math.PI * 2 - Math.PI / 2)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: as for appending the numbers to the tick marks? In this case we have 20 tick marks (0 to 1 with .05 steps). It would be nice to see how you tackle that when you have time.